# How to erase definition introduced by using Set instead of Equal in Solve

Tags: variable-definitions

When trying to solve a set of equations, I made a mistake by using `=` instead of `==`. Now when I fixed the mistake, the equation still always yield `True`. Switching the kernel off and back on would solve the problem, but is there a better way?

Sample code:

```
DSolve[y'[t] = 2, y[t], t]
(*DSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of 2
in the first argument 2*)

DSolve[y'[t] == 2, y[t], t]
(*DSolve[True, y[t], t]*)
```

Comment: maybe you might try something like Remove[y] or Remove["Global`"]?

Comment: `y'[t]=.` (the short form of `Unset`).

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar : You could have written your answer as an Answer...

Comment: @EricTowers Yes, could have but I think it is a candidate for "easily found in the docs" closure.

Comment: `Clear[y]` also works.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Could you explain why `Clear[y]` *doesn't* work? Thanks!

Comment: `Clear[y]` doesn't work because your mistaken definition is not associated with the symbol `y`. It is a `SubValue` of `Derivative` which is the Head of the FullForm of the expression. See [this question](http://Mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/96) for the answer to your probable next question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the docs:

Unset (=.)

lhs=.

removes any rules defined for lhs.

Rules are removed only when their left-hand sides are identical to lhs, up to renaming of patterns.

Undefine a value:

```
In[1]:= x = 5;

In[2]:= x =.

In[3]:= x

Out[3]= x
```